# Initial value not set on select dropdown wtih custom bindingshandler Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, materialize

I want to use Materialize with Knockout. But the normal way, from the documentation, doesn't work: 
`<select data-bind="options: AvailableCountries, optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'name', value: SelectedCountry"></select>`
The whole dropdown is just white and doesn't function

I have a custom handler here and it works, but it doesn't set the initial value. Does anyone know how to set it? The `SelectedCountry` is an `id`

```
    <select data-bind="materializeselect: { options: AvailableCountries },
               options: AvailableCountries,
               optionsValue: 'id',
               optionsText: 'name',
               value: SelectedCountry">
```

```
 ko.bindingHandlers["materializeselect"] = {
        after: ['options'],
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            // Initial initialization:
            $(element).material_select();

            valueAccessor().options.subscribe(function () {
                $(element).material_select();
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        }
    };
```

EDIT:
In the dropdown the right country is selected ( on initialization) and changes when I click a different country. Odd behavior.

Comment: Can you try by copying same code to update section as in init ?

Comment: That hasn't helped, sadly. Update never gets kicked off anyway, for some reason. Even though the 'value' does get updated, just not on load.